# WebService Prestashop API - edit module table

Tags: api, web-services, module, prestashop

I am trying to modify the table of a module via webService.

I have created the class in the module to access the table, I can access the data without problem. The php code of the module;
[image]

mySql table:

[image]

WebService response:

[image]

I think the problem may come with the labels

```
<megaproductcarts> 
<megaproductcart> 

</megaproductcart>
</megaproductcarts>
```

I have tried to pass the data without the parent tag and now the answer appears to be correct, but I don't see the modification in the database.

[image]

I would be very grateful for any help